# List the elements in the sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

I'm getting caught up in the notation here. Not entirely sure what it is saying. My interpretation:
(a,b) is an element of (the binary product) N x N then this "|" trips me up
My guess: the "a" element in the set is less than the b, the b is less than or equal to 3. 
Set B = (the notation for rational numbers) "|" a,b is an element in the set (-1, 1, 2)).

I think my biggest problem is with these "|" and what they mean.

Comment: "|" is a standard symbol whose meaning is "such that".

Comment: You will also see a colon in place of the pipe symbol, and it means exactly the same thing.